# Routing issue from virtual machine in weird network situation

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a a bit complicated network topology

I have a router from my ISP with the network 100.0.0.0/24, the router's IP is 100.0.0.1
My own Linksys router has 100.0.0.2 plus 192.168.1.1 for my LAN
I have a host which is via a switch connected to both the Linksys and the ISP-router,  it has the 192.168.1.5

I then installed a virtual machine on that host which should be available via the public  IP 100.0.0.3. I assigned it that address, and packages from outside get to the VM correctly, but they never come back. I probably need some special routing on the host, but I was not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: Your VM shall have the same IP address like your Linksys router? Does that make any sense? Does the router (100.0.0.1) know about the 192.168.1.0 network or does the Linksys router make NAT?

Comment: No, of course they shoudl not have the same IP. It was a typo (fixed it). The ISP router does not know about my LAN. The Linksys is doing NAT for my LAN, but I don't want the VMs traffic to be routed through it but rather directly t othe ISP-router.